# How can I clean my black glass cooktop surface?

Tags: cleaning, maintenance, protection, cooktops

I missed a step when I got my new [Cafe range](https://www.cafeappliances.com/appliance/Cafe-30-Smart-Slide-In-Front-Control-Radiant-and-Convection-Range-CES700P2MS1); the manual says...

BEFORE USING THE APPLIANCE...

> Use ceramic cooktop cleaner and a non-scratch cleaning pad to clean
> the cooktop. Wait until the cooktop cools and the indicator light goes
> out before cleaning. A wet sponge or cloth on a hot surface can cause
> steam burns. Some cleaners can produce noxious fumes if applied to a
> hot surface. See the Cleaning the glass cooktop section for detailed
> instructions.

From reading online it seems that some people think this initial step will somehow(?) protect the glass (somewhat?!) so that subsequent cleanings are much easier. Don't know, this is my first one.

Anyway, cleaning a black, glass cooktop sucks; it's a part time job just keeping it looking nice. I'll wipe it down nightly and do a once/week cleaning with vinegar, baking soda and lemon juice; that gets most of the jive off. Once/month I'll use the [Weiman's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LFKF7H6) on it and it looks pretty nice.

But, everyone I see cleaning something similar on YouTube seems to be doing a lot less work so I'm thinking about the initial step that I missed.

Pursuant to the original purpose, is there a way to seal it up ***now*** so it's easily cleanable later?

[image]

Comment: *"cleaning a black, glass cooktop sucks"* Correct. Had one for 5 years, will never have another. Just be glad you don't have a stainless steel splashback too ;))

Comment: I always thought that the initial clean (of anything new, really) is to remove any grease, debris, and so on, left over from manufacturing.

Comment: @Tetsujin, noted!

Comment: @AndrewMorton, the manual didn't say why it only said that it must be done. But that's a good point; lots of gross stuff on it from the trip home.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can be a pain to clean. I don't think it matter's that you missed a step in not cleaning it the first time. However to keep it looking good you need to clean it every time if you have spills. Do not use the stove if it is not entirely clean as it will just make it harder to clean up later. And you need to use the Weiman's a lot more often - at least once a week if not more often. You don't need to use much and all you need is a paper towel and a little elbow grease. You may need multiple applications if you have stubborn burnt on stuff.

TLDR; Clean after ever use - don't ever let it get too dirty

Comment: Just imagine spaghetti sauce on a plate, then you leave it out overnight, and then BAKE said dish in the oven. That's what happens if you cook when the surface is dirty.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I often use baking soda to clean mine, with a bit of dish detergent added to make a paste. Baking soda is granular enough to work well, and soft enough not to scratch the glass. If things are burnt on it may take a lot of rubbing, and alternating with hot water, but it does the job and is cheaper than the stuff sold for the purpose.

A plastic (not metal!) scraping edge may help in the worst cases. Or fingernails. Again, the goal is that the tool be softer than the glass.